# 3 divs hover at once

Tags: html, css, hover

I have 3 divs and I am trying to make them hover at once.
the 2 above are expanding and hiding the border and the stroke goes around them.Can  I do it with css?
This is my code:https://jsfiddle.net/ivailo/1hx4axpt/2/

```
.buttonmenu1{
height:176px;
width: 175px;
border: 1px solid #c2b6b4;
border-radius:7px;
background-color: rgba(215,209,194,.5);
position:relative;
left:186px;  
top:86px;

border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
overflow: hidden;

} 
.buttonmenu1:hover{
border: 0px solid #c2b6b4;
border-radius:0;
overflow:visible;
height:178px;
width:180px;
}



.buttonmenu1a{

height:27px;
background: rgb(202,224,130);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(202,224,130,.8) 55%, rgba(209,211,172,1) 85%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(202,224,130,.8) 55%,rgba(209,211,172,.1) 85%); 
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(202,224,130,.8) 55%,rgba(209,211,172,.1) 85%); 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cae082', endColorstr='#d1d3ac',GradientType=0 );
border-radius:7px;
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #9d9781;
}
.buttonmenu1b{
height: 1px;
background:white;
display: block;
margin : 2px 0px;
position:relative;
bottom:4px;
}
.textbuttonmenu1{
color:8a8556;
font-size:13pt;
position:relative;
left:56px;
top:3px;
opacity:.8
}

.svg-wrapper {
position: relative;

transform: translateY(-50%);
margin: 0 auto;
width: 320px;  
}
.shape {
stroke-dasharray: 140 540;
stroke-dashoffset: -474;
stroke-width: 8px;
fill: transparent;
stroke: #19f6e8;
border-bottom: 5px solid black;
transition: stroke-width 1s, stroke-dashoffset 1s, stroke-dasharray 1s; 
}
.svg-wrapper:hover .shape {
stroke-width: 2px;
stroke-dashoffset: 0;
stroke-dasharray: 1000;
}
```

Comment: For future users to know, you are suppose to accept an answer, if any, that solve your question, so it would be great if you could go through all your answers and accept the one's those that does, and the one's that miss something, let us know, so we can adjust, ... as we all benefit of knowing which answer solved a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample on how you can change 3 div's with 1 hover

You put the `:hover` on their parent.

```css
.as:hover .buttonmenu1a {
  background: blue;
}
.as:hover .buttonmenu1b {
  background: red;
}
.as:hover .svg-wrapper {
  background: lime;
}

.as2:hover .buttonmenu1a,
.as2:hover .buttonmenu1b,
.as2:hover .svg-wrapper {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="as">
  <div class="buttonmenu1">
    <div class="buttonmenu1a">A
    </div>
    <div class="buttonmenu1b">B
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="svg-wrapper">C
  </div>
</div>

<div class="as2">
  <div class="buttonmenu1">
    <div class="buttonmenu1a">A
    </div>
    <div class="buttonmenu1b">B
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="svg-wrapper">C
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey man I was thinking to replay I just lost myself in coding. I am thankful for the help and I am trying to show it in the comments and vote up, I just forgot. Thank you for your answer it worked as I wanted.